# Simple way to suppress SLDS and so use lightning-record-edit-form/lightning-input-field components inline?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, form

We would like to leverage the benefits of `lightning-record-edit-form`/`lightning-input-field` in terms of automatic coupling to field metadata and interaction with the Lightning Data Service, but present the fields embedded in free form text i.e. turn off the form row/column styling.

(This `variant="label-hidden"` turns off the label which is part of the solution.)

What is the best way to do this?

Here is a contrived example of the fields being inline:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
    Some text related to the first name
    <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="FirstName"></lightning-input-field>
    and the last name
    <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="LastName"></lightning-input-field>
    and the birth date
    <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="Birthdate"></lightning-input-field>
    and what might follow.
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Duh, writing this question prompted me to Google some different keywords to come up with the nice simple answer of `class="slds-form--inline"`:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" class="slds-form--inline">
    ...
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```